# UNIX: Find all directories that match string and copy a file there

Tags: unix

I was wondering how to file all directories that match a string and then if found, copy a file from root to that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find some/dir -type d -name foo.42 -exec cp somefile {} \;
```

Comment: thanks so much! saved me a lot of time. i really appreciate it.